# Strategies to load google font globally on expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an `expo` project and I am looking to load `google fonts` globally. I.e, I don't want to add `style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter-SemiBoldItalic', fontSize: 30 }}` on every `Text` in the project. I am using [this guide](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/user-interface/fonts/#use-a-google-font) but there is no mention on how to load fonts globally.

Comment: can you provide more detail?